# Angular ui grid disable sorting after cell edit

Tags: angular-ui-grid

For display tabular data , I am using angular ui-grid

if a column is sorted and then if we edit the cell, the sorting gets kicked in and moves the row. I would like to disable sorting on cell edit, is there any way to do this?

Plnkr    http://plnkr.co/edit/17H5K6nOEz9gf4Keeap9?p=preview

```
 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit >
  </div>

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.edit',
            'ui.grid.selection',
            'ui.grid.rowEdit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'A' },
      { field: 'B' },
      { field: 'C', enableSorting: false }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.data = [{'A':'a1', 'B':'b1', 'C':'c1'}, {'A':'a3', 'B':'b3', 'C':'c3'}, {'A':'a2', 'B':'b2', 'C':'c2'}];

});
```